Can accurate focus distance values be extracted from Panasonic RW2 EXIF metadata (from DC-S5M2 cameras?)
I recently generated a lensfun profile for a native L-mount lens (Panasonic's S-E100) which has very different vignetting characteristics at different focus distances. Accordingly, I generated (and measured) photos with focus at different positions -- but behavior in practice (where photos are often either overcorrected or undercorrected) makes me suspect that the editing software I'm using isn't detecting the focal distance in use and selecting the correct model parameters.
Using tools such as exiftool, FastRawViewer (a proprietary tool from the authors of the libraw open-source library), and others, I'm not seeing anything that looks like a focus distance in the metadata of RW2 files captured with my Panasonic DC-S5M2X. (Exiftool does show hyperfocal distance, but insofar as that's impacted by f-stop, it's quite a different value).
My understanding is that Panasonic hardware treats focus in "steps", but I'd hope that L-mount lens metadata would have a way to translate steps into centimeters.
Am I correct to be concerned that editing software (in particular, I'm using Affinity Photo 2) doesn't have enough metadata to select the correct parameters?

The focus step reported by Panasonic is a 0.5cm value. I.e. the focus distance in cm = step value/2.
https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8484.0

Assuming steps are some real physical thing like motor steps: Is it only 0.5cm at the closest focus?

Those values are for G-series cameras. There's no PanasonicRaw_0x0120 field at all in the RW2 files generated by my DC-S5M2X.

(I'm also quite sure that "0.5cm" isn't accurate for all lenses at all ranges -- using a 100mm macro lens, and telling it to take a batch of images 10 steps apart when focused near macro levels, the focal point certainly does not move 5cm between images in the resulting batch).

@CharlesDuffy, the S5M2 does report step value; so it should apply. What does the exif report for the step value for the macro batch series? I.e. the "steps" you specify in the menu may not be the same as what the exif is reporting.

@davolfman, IDK if steps can be actual focus motor steps; even if all of the lenses use the exact same motor and gearing the focus change would not be equivalent for different magnifications (at least I don't think so).

I'm having trouble finding steps in the EXIF data at all. See https://gist.githubusercontent.com/charles-dyfis-net/d2e0d84a82e70f98322d915391de74ab/raw/15be0cea2c48165325b4a3154b4c896a8346fb41/gistfile1.txt -- unless maybe PanasonicRaw_0x0120 is now Panasonic:DataDump?

@CharlesDuffy, exiftool will show it...

@StevenKersting The gist I linked is output from exiftool (in XML mode, which has more comprehensive output than the default mode -- but I can edit to add textual output as well if that helps).
